# remove no value given for one or more parameter

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I cant fix the code and it always show no value given for one or more parameter.I wonder what should i change to fix it.  my database is an access 2007

Try

```
        dataB = "Update login set  username = '" & txtUserName.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "' , dateofb = '" & dtpDOB1.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "', placeofb = '" & txtPOB.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "', email = '" & txtEmailID.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'  where userid = " & useridlbl.Text

        ConnDB()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(dataB, conn)
        Dim i As Integer
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If i > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Update Succesfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Confirmation")
            Me.Dispose()
            userinfofrm.Show()


        Else
            MsgBox("Failed Updating", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Alert!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()

    End Try
```

Comment: Could you please also add an diagram of your database?

Comment: Userid --text, username--text, pass--Text,  dateofb--Text, placeofb--text, email--text

Comment: If you check the value of dataB in the debugger, is there a question mark or a named parameter like `@parameterName` in the text?

Comment: Check carefully the names of your fields and the name of the table, one or more of them are spelled wrongly

Comment: no my dataB is just a string

Comment: the name also in field and in table is correct i alreadycheck it not just twice

Comment: If this answers the question, please click the checkmark so it moves off the UnAnswered list; this also helps others find good answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the query I suspect that the email address is the root of the problem as it contains an `@` character. The OleDbCommand interprets this as a parameter and therefore looks for a parameter value. As you didn't specify the parameter value, the error is raised.

In order to solve this, better use parameters in your query right away. Though you escape single quotation marks in your statement, it is much safer to use parameters in order to prevent SQL injection attacks. Parameters also circumvent problems regarding region specific formats of date values and such. In addition, using parameterized queries allows the database server (or MS access) to cache the query plan for subsequent requests.

Change your statement as follows:

```vb
dataB = "Update login set  username = @userName, dateofb = @dateOfB, " + _
        "placeofb = @placeOfB, email = @email where userid = @userId "

ConnDB()

cmd = New OleDbCommand(dataB, conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtUserName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfB", DateTime.Parse(dtpDOB1.Text))  ' Maybe your control can provide you with the DateTime value right away
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@placeOfB", txtPOB.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmailID.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", useridlbl.Text)

Dim i As Integer
i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
' ...
```

Please note that I've used the named parameter syntax that MS Access understands. Other OleDB providers might need unnamed parameters in form of a question mark. As @Steve points out in the comments, the order of the parameters in the statement should match the order in which they are added to the `Parameters` collection.

Comment: @Markus I would also add a note on the fact that the parameter position in the collection is really what makes OleDb recognize them.

Comment: @Steve: thanks for the hint, I've updated the answer accordingly.